# PFQuery whereKey: containedIn: query doesn't works

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my `PFUser` class every user has a key called `twitterId`, which contains their twitter ID. After I obtained the friend list of the `currentUser` from Twitter I can't find these values with a Parse query, despite these ID's are assigned to PFUsers.

I don't really understand why this happens, because when I take the first item of the `friends` array and use the `equalTo` instead of `containedIn` it works perfectly.

This is the solution that I want to use, but doesn't works. The array has values, and these values are assigned to other users, therefore I don't have any idea what's wrong. I would really appreciate if somebody could explain me what did I wrong, because it seems correct for me.

```
- (void) listTwitterFriends:(NSArray *)friends {

    PFQuery *queryFriends = [PFUser query];
    [queryFriends whereKey:@"twitterId" containedIn:friends];
    [queryFriends findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"OBJECTS AFTER QUERY %@", objects);

    }];
}
```

This is the working version

```
- (void) listTwitterFriends:(NSArray *)friends {

    NSString *devSt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", friends[0]];

    NSLog(@"First friend ID %@", devSt);

    PFQuery *queryFriends = [PFUser query];
    [queryFriends whereKey:@"twitterId" equalTo: devSt];
    [queryFriends findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"OBJECTS AFTER QUERY %@", objects);

    }];
}
```

Comment: Are the objects in your array strings?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: @Babac No, I didn't use this function in that app, but I think with the latest SDK's it should work, maybe it was because of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, however seemed like the strings I was adding to the array of strings to compare where mutable, changing
`[friends addObject:friend[@"id"]];` to `[friends addObject:[friend[@"id"] copy]];` worked for me.
Make sure the array you pass to `listTwitterFriends:` contains objects which types match you parse related key value's type, watch out for mutable versions.